# A positive definite Hermitian form

Tags: linear-algebra

Acoording to [the deifinition of the Hermitian Form](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/HermitianForm.html)

, given an analytic function $f: \mathbb D \to \mathbb D$, suppose that $f(z_k) = w_k$, I can form a Hermitian form on $\mathbb C^n$ by defining $H = \sum_{h,k = 1}\frac{1-w_h\bar w_k}{1-z_h\bar z_k}t_h\bar t_k$. What does it mean by saying such a Hermitian form is positive definite? I cannot find any formal definition for it online.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quadratic form $f : \mathbf{C}^n \times \mathbf{C}^n \to \mathbf{C}$ is positive semidefinite if $f(x,x) \ge 0$ for all $x$. It is positive definite if $f(x,x) = 0$ only when $x = 0$.